# Rodar script apenas quando a tela estiver desligada

Tags: javascript, script, automatização

Fala galera, estou tentando automatizar rotinas do celular com um app que fiz e pra deixar ele mais eficaz estou tentando implementar um script para ele rodar sempre que a tela do celular estiver desligada. Por exemplo: se a tela estiver desligada > rodar o script, fazer todas as atualizações + rodar antivirus + outras funções que o usuário escolher automatizar. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, fico grato.

Answer (score 1):

Quando se trata de rotina do aparelho: detectar modo de desligamento. No android, por exemplo, temos o:

`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON`

> Você não conseguirá nada SOMENTE com javascript...

### Estude o que está listado abaixo para poder seguir uma linha de javascript / frontend:

- IONIC
- React Native